# Char Array in Struct printing garbage

Tags: c, string, struct, initialization

when I run this, the partName char array prints garbage chars. any idea why? Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
char partName[30]; 
int partNumber; 
float price; 
int stock; 
int reorder;
} inventory;
struct address{
char streetAddress[25]; 
char city[20];
char state[3]; 
char zipCode[6];
};
void GetData(){

inventory order;
address orderAddress;
printf("Enter the part number (Database Includes orders 0001 - 0005):  ");

scanf("%d", &order.partNumber);

if(order.partNumber == 0001){
order.partName == "Pokeball";
order.price == 200;
order.stock == 8263;
order.reorder == 888273;

orderAddress.streetAddress == "21 Oak St.";
orderAddress.city == "Kanto Town";
orderAddress.state == "IA";
orderAddress.zipCode == "28832";

printf("Part was: %s ", order.partName);
//printf("Order was sent to: \n %s\n %s\n %s\n %s\n", orderAddress.streetAddress,         orderAddress.city, orderAddress.state, orderAddress.zipCode);
 }
```

It's printing some random chars, and I'm sure it's a simple error somewhere.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: You should assign a value to a variable before you attempt to print it.

Comment: try this strcpy(order.partName, "Pokeball");

Comment: If you didn't get compiler warnings for this code, you need to check how to enable more warnings on your compiler, or get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following aren't *assignments*. They are *comparisons*:

```
order.partName == "Pokeball";
order.price == 200;
order.stock == 8263;
order.reorder == 888273;

orderAddress.streetAddress == "21 Oak St.";
orderAddress.city == "Kanto Town";
orderAddress.state == "IA";
orderAddress.zipCode == "28832";
```

To assign to integers, write

```
order.price = 200;
```

To assign to C strings, use [`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) et al.

Comment: There we go, rookie mistake. Thank you!